# Transform cat file.txt | wc -l program code c

Tags: c, linux

I'm very newbie about pipes and I want develop a little program for understand and learn about this. My idea consist to communicate command shell cat to wc using c. I was doing a very simple program that use an exiting file (test.txt for example) but for the moment I can only display the content. I only want count the number of lines about 1 specific file.

Is this possible to implement? Or maybe I must do another option? Here my basic code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];

    pipe(fd);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);    
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
        close(fd[0]);
        execlp("cat", "cat", "test.txt", NULL);
        //I don't know how communicate this process with the other process
    } else {
        /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey check mark below its score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must redirect the appropriate end of the pipe to standard input and/or standard output before the call to `execlp()`.  If this call succeeds, the current process has been replaced with the new one, no further code is executed, but if it fails, you should complain with a `perror()`.

Here is a corrected version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];

    if (pipe(fd)) {
        perror("pipe");
        return 1;
    }

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        /* Child process redirects its output to the pipe */
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp("cat", "cat", "test.txt", NULL);
        perror("exec cat");
        return 1;
    } else {
        /* Parent process redirects its input from the pipe */
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
        perror("exec wc");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) Works perfectly !

Comment: One question: Why double close (fd[0]) and close (fd[1])??

Comment: @vikitus: `fd[0]` and `fd[1]` are closed before the `execlp` system call to prevent the next process from inheriting these handles. The appropriate end of the pipe has been duplicated into the standard input or output, the original pipe handles are no longer used in the current process and should not be transmitted to the exec'ed process.

Answer (score 0):

if you only care about the number of lines in the file you can just run the entire command using popen and then read the output for output or any error

```
e.g. fd = popen("cat test.txt | wc -l", "r");
```

then use `read` method to read the output. you can also use return value from `pclose(fd)` to check if process completed successfully.